# What are those black spots on my apples?

Tags: diagnosis, fruit-trees, apples

I've got two apple trees in the garden and all of their apples are covered in black spots

[image: Apple]

What is this? They are quite different from those [What causes black spots on my apples?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1605/what-causes-black-spots-on-my-apples)

Any idea how to treat this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks a lot like [Apple scab](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_scab), a fungal infection with [venturia inaequalis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venturia_inaequalis) that is very common. The fungus is harmless for human consumption and the scabs can be peeled, but the damaged skin can faciliate entry of mold etc., thus negatively influencing storage of the fruit.

The best prevention would have been planting a scab-resistant apple, but this is too late in your case.
In case of an infection, apart from fungicide<sup>1</sup>, there are a few measures to reduce re-infection:

- Remove all fallen leaves (infected leaves have dark spots like the one in the left of the apple in your photo, they also tend to drop earlier) and infected twigs to reduce the amount of "winter spores".
- Regular pruning ensures a loose, airy crown that can dry quickly, making it harder for the spores to take root.

---

<sup>1</sup> Whether you choose to take the fungicide route is up to you. Your case appears mostly "cosmetic", so if you can live with a few scabs, simply keeping up with removal of infected material could be enough. Keep your tree well-nourished (not simply fertilized, check what it really needs) and strong and it can resist the fungus.