# What's growing on my tomatoes?

Tags: diagnosis, tomatoes

My tomato plants are covered with tiny, pill-like growths on their stems, pictured below. They're about 1mm wide and 3-4mm long, and they're widespread on both stems and branches. I'm also getting an early rot that turns my tomatoes brown, which may be related.

[image: Infections on tomato stems]

What is this, and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: @JSBangs, I believe ["Mancuniensis" answer](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1512/whats-growing-on-my-tomatoes/1513#1513) is a good one, but posting a photo of the whole plant & one showing a damaged fruit, might be of some benefit...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These are the tiny hairs on the stems trying to turn into roots, above ground; they are called **stem primordia**, and this is usually caused by high humidity, over-watering or prolonged rain - see [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:6kpHtxrO9iIJ:www.veggiegardener.com/tomato-quirks-bumpy-stems/%20tomato%20stems%20covered%20in&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk&client=firefox-a&source=www.google.co.uk).

Generally speaking, this is nothing to worry about, and is best ignored; however, it can be triggered by root problems or disease, and given that some of your tomatoes are rotting, it could be a bad sign and worth looking into - see [Blossom End Rot - here.](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/987/what-else-besides-calcium-deficiency-could-be-causing-tomato-blossom-end-rot/992#992)