# Why is this tomato rotten at the end, and loosened from the plant?

Tags: diagnosis, vegetables, tomatoes, fruits

On of my tomato is rotten at the bottom. At the same time I observe that the  connection between the plant and fruit is broken. Not sure what happened first though. Is this just a physical damage that caused rotting? Am I missing calcium?

[image][image]
[image][image]
[image]

Comment: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/987/what-else-besides-calcium-deficiency-could-be-causing-tomato-blossom-end-rot

Comment: what about that break line?

Comment: That's the plant giving up on the fruit and cutting its losses.

Answer (score 3):

That doesn't look like calcium deficiency. I think your fruit is simply dying from being cut from the plant. It must've been knocked or jostled, but not enough to knock it loose. The connected fruit looks healthy, as do the leaves. You can pick it off if you want, it doesn't matter.